# ¿Como puedo ocultar el mes de un datepicker de angular material?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Estoy tratando de ocultar/remover el mes, que esta dentro de la sección de días del datepicker de angular material:

Por default, solo aparece

**En color rojo:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" class="pt-2" (click)="picker.open()">
    <mat-label>Elige un día</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker">
    <mat-datepicker #picker [calendarHeaderComponent]="exampleHeader"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: revisa este enlace https://www.concretepage.com/angular-material/angular-material-datepicker-start-view-month-year-multi-year

Comment: intenta con: [startView]="'year'"

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser un manejo de selectores en el css, de momento esto me ayudo a ocultarlo, encontre la respuesta [aquí](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/12612)

```
.mat-calendar-body-label:not(:last-of-type) {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.mat-calendar-body-label:last-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```